# Certificados push notification

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

Tengo una duda, tengo una app que se cargue al app store sin antes haber generado el certificado y todos los pasos para que funcione con notificaciones remotas, ahora ya genere los pasos para las notificaciones pero no funciona, las notificaciones se envían pero no llegan a los dispositivos, tendría que subir de nuevo la app al apple store para que tome la configuración nueva de los certificados ?

Gracias

Answer (score 5):

si, vas a tener que asociar dichos certificados en el Xcode, hacer todos los pasos y volver a generar la aplicación de nuevo.

Un saludo.